# Django installation on virtual environemnt

Tags: django, installation

when I want to install django with easy_install on a virtual environment error occurs saying
bash: /home/..../django-virtualenv/bin/easy_install: : bad interpreter: No such file or directory

However when I use sudo for global installation there is no any problem. Couldn't figure out what is a problem.

Comment: Did u tried **source your_virt_env_dir/bin/activate** before using easy_install?

Comment: use pip is better than easy_install

Comment: can you install other packages in that virtualenv?  seems like a problem with the virtualenv itself rather than Django.  "bad interpreter" sounds like a problem with the Python install

Comment: easy install does not work at all actually in virtual env

Comment: Try using Pycharm. Set up the interpreter with the virtual env, then use a REQUIREMENTS.txt and define all of your projects requirements in there (dont forget to tell pycharm in the settings that you have this). Restart Pycharm, then it will prompt you to install those requirements, and it will automatically go into the virtual env. Pycharm is also good for working with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Just use pip, it come by default with your virtualenv

```
pip install django
```